# What criteria to focus on when selecting a BLE module?

Tags: electrical-engineering, wireless-communication

I am trying to select a BLE module for low power application. I have looked into different BLE modules from different chip manufacturers. For example:

1. [ISM78G1D Bluetooth Low Energy SIP from Inventek](https://www.inventeksys.com/products-page__trashed/ble/ble/)
2. [Blue Gecko BGM13S Bluetooth® Module - SiP from Silicon Labs](https://www.silabs.com/products/wireless/bluetooth/bluetooth-low-energy-modules/bgm13s-bluetooth-sip-module)
3. [SimpleLink Multi-Standard CC2652R Wireless MCU from TI](http://www.ti.com/product/CC2652R)
4. [EZ-BLE and EZ-BT Bluetooth Modules from Cypress](http://www.cypress.com/products/ez-ble-and-ez-bt-bluetooth-modules)
5. [nRF52840 from Nordic Semiconductor](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/nRF52840)
6. [Samsung ARTIK™ 020](https://www.artik.io/modules/artik-020/)

I am in the process of learning strategies on selecting a BLE module given a few choices. The application will be used in a low power application which includes a sensor to detect objects. We plan to connect the BLE module to the host micro-controller controlling the sensor. The BLE module will communicate to a Gateway (currently being defined) that will transmit the data to the cloud.

Appreciated if someone can provide some guidance on what criteria to use when selecting a BLE module. Thanks for your help!

Comment: As-is, this question is far too broad. The relevant characteristics depend on your particular use-case, and what's... well, relevant to you. Please [edit] your question describing your case and what characteristics are important to you. We'll then try to convert those to the relevant technical specifications.

Comment: @Wasabi, thanks for your feedback. I am rewording the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at if the device supports BLE 4.0, 4.1, 4.2 or 5.0 is a good start. Not all BLE modules are 5.0 capable. What type is distance range might be a parameter to consider some BLE module have line of sight range of 1km or more at a low data rates. Below is a short side by side comparison to help get started.

[image]